# Install Opencv in custom directory?

Tags: opencv, installation, pkg-config

How to install OpenCV in a custom directory on linux? I would like to install from the latest source code (version 3.0), but without touching the current version (4.6.0) installed on my computer.

I know I can use CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to specify a custom dir, but how will pkg-config handle the two versions then?

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Comment: You can rename pkg-config file for OpenCV 3.0 after installation (eg. `opencv3.pc`):

    pkg-config --libs opencv -> OpenCV 2.4    
    pkg-config --libs opencv3 -> OpenCV 3.0

Comment: Thx! So if I understand correctly I  have to rename the line (n°9) "Name: OpenCV" to "Name: OpenCV3" in the opencv.pc from my latest version, and then give OpenCV3 to pkg-config in my opencv3 c++ project.

Comment: I mean rename the file name `opencv.pc` -> `opencv3.pc`.

Comment: how will pkg-config know that I changed this filename? Does it have a path to the directory where the opencv package files lie, and it scans it when necessary to find the appropriate package file?

Comment: I renamed the file, used `PKGCONFIG += opencv3` and I got `error: Package opencv3 not found`

Comment: `pkg-config --libs opencv3` returns me the libs, but I still have `error: Package opencv3 not found`

Comment: Add path to `opencv3.pc` to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` enviroment variable.

Comment: Yes, I thought I did it, but I realized I used the wrong opencv.pc file. I was using the one in the cmake_binary_dir/unix-install/, but I should probably use the one in install_dir/lib/pkgconfig/.

Comment: I did the same thing and `pkg-config --libs opencv3` returns me the libs. But when I compile my code using g++ then it gives an error as ```libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_max_concurrency(tbb::interface7::task_arena const*) ```. Anyone have idea about this error?